# How can Eclipse perform a maven build before a junit test to replace variables?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I've a pretty big maven project with some integration tests (JUnit). At the end that project will be build with Maven and during the build Maven will exchange some variables in some files like `${project.version.major}` or `${project.version.minor}` with the corresponding value. Those values will be used to create a lookup on the service on the testing server. There are dozens of working integration tests if I use maven to build or let Jenkins build them. So I don't want to change the tests, just the setup so Eclipse uses maven to build.

The same tests are also working for other devs. But they don't have a special run configuration and no one remembers doing anything special to make them run as they should. So I guess it may be a very basic thing I am doing wrong.

That works pretty well if I perform a `mvn clean install`. Unfortunately if I run the test in Eclipse it won't exchange the values and the test will fail with a NameNotFoundException. The tests currently run as JUnit test, though I have the same problem with a small test java application in the same project.

**How can I convince Eclipse to perform a `mvn clean install` when I run it instead of the build in compiler?** (or any other solution that will work)

*Please ELI5, I am still trying to figure out Eclipse*

Comment: Why are you changing those informations? Are you developing a plugin or what are trying to achieve?

Comment: Create a service that reads the version numbers. In test, mock the service and return what you want. In production, use a concrete service that reads from your files. Would that work for you?

Comment: Whatever other will tell you, if it's a part of your application it sounds fishy. Please let us know why you want to do that

Comment: @khmarbaise - It's part of our infrastructure. Summarized: We always call something with the same version number so it's important that those information always get replaced with the current version of the project.

Comment: @Duncan - There are already dozens of working integration tests that work well in Jenkins. I just want Eclipse to behave the same.

Comment: You cannot change the build behavior in Eclipse (except for writing a custom builder perhaps). But you can run MVN commands from a right-click on the project in the "Run as" menu.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose - I don't want to run the whole project, just one single test class. There I have only a "Run as JUnit", there has to be something that I configure in the run configuration for the test. The same tests work for other devs with Eclipse... but no one knows why.

Comment: "The same tests work for other devs with Eclipse" - This would have been an important information in your question. You should update it. Additionally, why not simply check their run configurations? Or - maybe - there is a custom builder they have attached?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose - They're currently out of office. Hoped I could figure it out "myself" before they're back.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose - Ha, found one I could ask... unfortunately there is no special run configuration. It's just a unit test.

Comment: They might probably be right clicking on the project and doing a Run As > Maven Install (or any other lifecycle which generates the required classes or resources for your test) before they go into the test case and run it as a JUNIT test. Might be able to help you if you could provide the pom configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Eclipse has the Maven Integration features/plugins installed (aka, "m2e", see https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/download/). When that is installed and the project isconfigured as a Maven project, it will take care of the parts of build phases that maven does from command line, such as replacing variables in your resources.